# Concatenate rows into a text string

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

This question has probably been answered and I have found part of the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11892100/4442529) for Postgres.

I am running version 9.1 of Postgres and this is what I am trying to do.
I have a table:

```
 col1 |   col2    | col
------------------------
  1   | 1 jan 12  | Joe
  1   | 1 jan 12  | Bill
  1   | 1 jan 12  | Sue
  2   | 2 may 13  | Bob
  2   | 2 may 13  | Mary
```

I want:

```
 col1 |   col2    | col3
------------------------
  1   | 1 jan 12  | Joe, Bill, Sue
  2   | 2 may 13  | Bob, Mary
```

I am sure the solution is simple, I just have not been able to come up with it despite searching. I am guessing that `array_agg` is probably part of my solution.

Comment: It's very counter-intuitive to use "row1" as ***column*** name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `String_agg` function

```
SELECT row1,
       row2, 
       string_agg(row3, ',') as row3
FROM your_table
GROUP BY row1,
         row2
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This did the trick. Also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12365699/4442529) for anyone else needing this answer.